# ASP.NET Web API map a custom exception to a HTTP error code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This question is about

- software development methods and good practices and
- architecture

I'm working on a Web API in C# using Web API MVC. Here is a sample of one of my controller:

```
    public class LayoutController : ApiController
    {
        private const string ControllerName = "Layout";

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Item/{itemCode}/Layout")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAll(string itemCode)
        {
            using (var itemService = new ItemService())
            using (var layoutService = new LayoutService())
            {
                var item = itemService.Read(itemCode);
                var layouts = layoutService.List(item);
                return Ok(layouts);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Item/{itemCode}/Layout/{layoutName}", Name = ControllerName + nameof(Get))]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string itemCode, string layoutName)
        {
            using (var itemService = new ItemService())
            using (var layoutService = new LayoutService())
            {            
                try
                {
                    var item = itemService.Read(itemCode);
                    var layout = layoutService.Read(item, layoutName);
                    return Ok(layout);
                }
            }
            catch (NotFoundException)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
```

As you can see I work with controller and what I call `services`. My services are kind of repository. Services are made to create, read, update, delete and list my entities.

I also created a NotFoundException that I raise when something is not found in my services. Example of a service that use this NotFoundException:

```
    public class LayoutService : SingletonBaseService<LayoutService>, IRepository<Item, Layout>
    {
        public Layout Read(Guid id)
        {
            var layout = Context.Layouts
                .SingleOrDefault(y => y.Id == id)
                ?? throw new NotFoundException($"Layout {id} not found");

            return layout;
        }
```

I never know what to do. Return exception or return null value? I have the feeling working with null and returning null is always starting doing something wrong so I prefer working with exception. But maybe I'm wrong and you will tell me why?

So I choose to catch my NotFoundException to return a NotFound(). I chosse this because in some controller I can call a lot of services. In case my services return null value I will have to evaludate each return value after each call on a service. This can complexify a code like this:

```
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string itemCode, string subitemCode, string layoutName)
        {
            using (var itemService = new ItemService())
            using (var layoutService = new LayoutService())
            {
                var item = itemService.Read(itemCode);
                if (item == null)
                    return NotFound();

                var subItem = itemService.Read(subitemCode);
                if (subitem == null)
                    return NotFound();

                var layout = layoutService.Read(item, subItem, layoutName);
                if (layout == null)
                return NotFound();
                else
                    return Ok(layout);
            }
        }
```

When it could be simply

```
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string itemCode, string subitemCode, string layoutName)
        {
            using(var itemService = ItemService())
            using(var layoutService = LayoutService())
                try
                {
                    var item = itemService.Read(itemCode);
                    var subItem = itemService.Read(subitemCode);
                    var layout = layoutService.Read(item, subItem, layoutName);
                    return Ok(layout);
                }
                catch(NotFoundException)
                    return NotFound();
            }
        }
```

But now I have the feeling it is possible to tell ASP.NET MVC system that all my NotFoundException shoud return a NotFound(). Is it correct? Then i throw my exception and I dont have to write try catch in all my controllers. I can focus on the most important.

Comment: As an aside to your question, I got as far as `ItemService.Instance` and thought, "No! He's using global variables!" :'( Please consider using dependency injection instead.

Comment: It won't help with regards to your question. It'll make your code less error prone and far easier to test though. Service locators, especially ones sitting behind a global variable, are a definite anti-pattern.

Comment: "*there are already a lot of paper that moved DI as anti pattern also*". No, there really aren't. Your choice of course. I was merely offering my advice that you are using an anti-pattern and thus writing poor code. You are free to disregard that advice. It was freely given and you are free to ignore it.

Comment: Think about this. Really repositories *must* throw a new exception when the certain ID is not found? Is that so critically that must fail so fast from so irrelevant layer (persistence)? An unknown ID is a problem that concerns persistence? Or rather concerns business? In other words. If you execute an SQL on Oracle filtering by an unknown Id. Does Oracle break the execution? Or just returns 0 rows? Why your repository is responsible for deciding whether an unknown Id must break the execution?

Comment: "*it will force me to write a lot of more code for no benefit*". Please see [this answer to the question, *So Singletons are bad, then what?*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/40610/105684) for why your claim of "*no benefit*" is utterly wrong.

Comment: I still find that very interesting to see how people tell you what is good, what is bad, pattern, anti-pattern without knowing your background. How they can tell you must remove dependencies by just creating new one they don't see. Dependency to pattern or complexity is one of them. For those people are you working in a team on long term maintenance project or are you one of these super consultant that cannot stay on a project more than a year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, what is the goal from throwing the Exception? Exceptions represent errors within the application, not simply a null or not found value. Just simply return a 404 NotFound response to the user.

Also, throwing exceptions are expensive actions and will affect performance of your application. They should be used sparingly and definitely not in this case.

As for how you can refactor that code to make it a little cleaner, you could do something as simple as this.

```
  public IHttpActionResult Get(string itemCode, string subitemCode, string layoutName)
    {
        var item = ItemService.Instance.Read(itemCode);
        var subItem = ItemService.Instance.Read(subitemCode);
        var layout = LayoutService.Instance.Read(item, subItem, layoutName);

        if(item is null || subItem is null || layout is null) return NotFound();

        return Ok(layout);
    }
```

I'm not sure what the context of your application data/domain model is like, but maybe consider combining some of those queries into one. For example, if you use `item` and `subItem` to construct a `layout` , make a repository method that will do all the required queries in one method call and then return you your `layout` object. You can implement the repository to do the null checks for each required item and if one is null, then just return null from the method. You can then just use one null check in your controller.

Without knowing a bit more about your application and model, it's hard to really give any good suggestions. But hopefully this can help you clean it up a bit.

Comment: "Also, as a tip, using try-catch blocks and throwing exceptions are expensive actions and will affect performance of your application" Typical answer I cannot accept. 1. try catch does not cost anything more, throw cost more. Too many people still does the confusion. 2. whatever you think I must catch something because I'm not in control of exception raise by my database. Well IIS will catch them if I do not. Whatever who catch them in fact. Exception can happen point, so it will cost. This is not because you are not writing your try-catch you are not getting throwable.

Comment: And event if you do all you if database exists, if database is connected, if data exist, if data is not duplicate, if everything when you finally do the call it may Always be possible this next microseconde, picosecond all what your just tested is not true anymore. Exception happens. POINT.

Comment: if(item is null || subItem is null || layout is null) return NotFound(); First my example is very simple but most of the time I use data of tiem for next call and son on. Then, really, it is better to catch as sonn as possible to accept 3 call to database. database call are time consuming operations. So better catch error and avoid further call when possible. That I'm sure.

Comment: I agree in principle with this answer. A query which returns no matching results is a common _and expected_ path through your code... there's no reason to use an exception to handle normal program flow. Exceptions should be catching unexpected situations, like the database is broken or network connectivity is down. The example refactoring provided is good and well represents the case where the query was successfully completed but no matching results were found. I agree with the criticism though, that throwing exceptions will likely not have a noticeable impact on performance.

Comment: Hence why I said "and throwing Exceptions". That was probably a miscommunication on my part. I only mentioned that because, at least in my opinion, it seems like a non optimal choice to use in a web API controller action that may receive significant load. Throwing an exception for control flow, in a case that may happen frequently and is non critical, will have a negative impact on performance if the app ever needs to scale to handle many requests per second.

Comment: The cost of handling the controller action almost certainly far exceeds the cost of a thrown exception.

Comment: @EricKing People seems agree with you but you all forget that whatever you do exception is part of the process. Not only for unexpected situation. This by design of .NET and ASP.NET itself. When you do a Single() and even a SingleOrDefault() you can still get an exception on multiple result found. I ask myself why working with null when Microsoft and .NET is fighting these practice more and more. Why?

Comment: @BastienVandamme I still disagree to some extent. Exceptions should not be used to direct regular, expected program flow. As for Single() and SingleOrDefault(), that's a great example of using exceptions to signify an unexpected, breaking bug. You use Single() when you expect 1 and only 1 result, as in a GetByPrimaryKey() function. Finding two records that match a single primary key signifies a serious (broken) data problem, and so an exception is appropriate. If you are OK with more than one match, then you signify that by using First() or FirstOrDefault() instead.

Comment: I agree with @EricKing 's answer. Yes exceptions are a necessary tool, but we are just suggesting that in your use case, it may not be the most optimal solution.

Comment: @EricKing I'm also agree with you. Exceptions are only for serious broken data problem. And you agree with me at same time. When you expect to have one and only one result you will use Single(). So you will never return null value in this case. You will not use SingleOrDefault expect if you consider it may be possible you cannot find the data.

Comment: @BastienVandamme Actually, that's exactly when you _should_ use SingleOrDefault. If the query can return zero or one result, _that's what SingleOrDefault is for_. I do not agree with you that it is ok to raise an exception when a routine query that _may_ return no data _actually returns_ no data.

Comment: @EricKing I don't know what I said before but if fact I agree with you on both formulation. But you know... logic ;-)